# powershell add objects via -outvariable +variable in a function

Tags: function, powershell

I am running in an imported session window. Not sure if that matters.

I am trying to add a few variable values to an array in a function.

```powershell
$Session = New-PsSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri "http://emailserver/powershell/" -Authentication Kerberos
Import-PsSession $Session -allowclobber
Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell

$group1 = "Accounting"
$group2 = "HR"

function AddUsersToGroups {
  Write-output $Group1 -outvariable +Adgroups
  Write-output $Group2 -outvariable +Adgroups
}
```

When I highlight and run the lines from a Powershell ISE they work fine and create the Variable $AdGroups and the combined data is in there.

But when I run the function all I see is the output and no variable gets created.

```powershell
PS C:\Windows\system32> AddUserToGroups
Group1
Group2
```

Kinda Stumped. I tried to create a variable `$AdGroups = @()` as the first line but it fails also.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve, but the `AdGroups` variable will be available  only in the scope of the `AddUsersToGroups` function.

One way of solving this would be add the `script:` scope, like below:

```
Function AddUsersToGroups{
  Write-output $Group1 -outvariable +script:Adgroups
  Write-output $Group2 -outvariable +script:Adgroups
}
```

Now you should be able to access `$Adgroups` outside after the function is called.